# Add libraries to Xcode in external build system project

Tags: xcode

I have a project (gba programming), and due to the fact that I use an external make file (too much hassle with custom architecture otherwise) I use an "external build system" project. How do I add those custom libraries (placed in /opt/somedir) so Xcode's "jump to definition" would work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

An ugly, yet effective solution is to add a fictional target, that is set up to be build with Xcode, and set as target for all the headers and original target files. Then they will be properly indexed. Of course, this target is purely for indexing and is not supposed to be actually built.